# Technical term for this kind of PLC I/O?

Tags: terminology, plc

I don't claim to be an electrical engineer or even an electrician as I work with software more often than hardware, my job does however often work with panel wiring and wiring I/O; I was hoping someone could define a type of wiring for some technical documentation I'm putting together?

The component being used is a Phoenix [ILB ETH 24 DI16 DIO16-2TX](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?urile=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2832962) wired to support simple outputs and inputs using the image below:[image: Input wiring][image: Output wiring]

I would generally feel to these as PNP/NPN but I think this only apply to a circuit using a transistor? Any explanation as to explain this type of wiring would be great as I understand the practical side but not the theory.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, but I would call the inputs "Sinking", and the outputs "Sourcing", which is probably the most common configuration in general industry.

Comment: It was a tad vague question as I'm not sure the best way of wording it but that sounds like exactly what I was I was hoping for, I'll have a google of them. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know enough about it but from other questions here, I think that "PNP and "NPN" are commonly used terms for this in the PLC world (but they are confusing to EE's who don't work with PLCs). Unfortunately I don't think there's too many PLC people answering questions here so I'm not sure you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys! R. Drast you were spot on, I looked into Sinking Inputs and Sourcing Outputs and they were exactly the type or wiring I needed to write about. Apparently an input or output like this used to be achieved using PNP/NPN transistors connecting Load to Ground and viceversa which must be why I had those terms from people throwing them about the office.

Comment: PNP and NPN are the standard industry terms, for better or worse.

Comment: Re: sourcing/sinking of inputs... If the input is `on` when the input pin is seeing + voltage then the input is said to be "sourcing". i.e. a switch between + and the input. A "sinking" input would see - (or gnd) to indicate `on`.

Answer (score 1):

In Figures 1 and 2, below, an external sensor is connected to a PLC input. Let's assume that the PLC input has an opto-coupler to the internal logic to isolate the sensitive logic circuitry from the outside world. The circuit, as far as external switches are concerned, is an LED with series resistor. If we short the input terminal to the common terminal we should expect about 5 to 15 mA to flow (determined by the internal series resistor).

In Figure 1. The opto-LED anode is connected to +24 V supply and the cathode is connected through the resistor to the input pin. When the input pin is connected to COMM- the LED will light giving a logic '1' to the PLC CPU. We can, of course, use a switch contact to do this but many interfaces will use a transistor. Either way, the PLC input provides or sources the current through the LED (red arrow) and is known as a "sourcing" input. Since NPN transistors can be very easily switched in this configuration they are generally used - hence "NPN" inputs.

[image: NPN - sourcing input.]

One major advantage of this arrangement is that the transistor can be powered from a supply of different voltage to the PLC - e.g., a 5 V micro-controller and once it shares the common negative it effectively becomes a level shifter between the two systems.

The main disadvantage is that the logic is somewhat inverted. A high voltage on the input is logic 0 and a low voltage is logic 1. This can be confusing.

[image: PNP - sinking input.]

Figure 2 shows the PNP / sinking circuit. Here current flows from the + supply, through the transistor and the PLC "sinks" it.

The logic is the right way up now and this style of input is preferred on most industrial equipment at present.

For outputs the situation is similar. A current sourcing output will supply the current from the + supply, through the load to the COMM-. For a current sinking output the current will flow from the + supply, through the load, into the PLC input where an NPN transistor will "sink" it to COMM-.

Note some PLCs use bi-directional opto-isolators - two LEDs connected in opposite directions. By connecting the input common terminal to + or - supply the inputs can be made sourcing or sinking.

Comment: The PLC has the same NPN photocoupler in both these images.  I think you mean "PLC port is designed for NPN/PNP sensor", not "PLC port is NPN/PNP"?

Comment: That is correct.